# sampling without replacement in C for use in R code

Tags: c, r

I am trying to write a function in C that will be called by R.  Within it I need to take a random sample without replacement from a vector.  Is it possible with Rmath.h to use something like sample() in R? If not, does anyone know why I might be getting

```
    Symbol not found: _gsl_rng_mt19937
```

When I try to dyn.load() code that calls that includes (with the appropriate headers):

```
      #include <gsl/gsl_randist.h>
      #include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>

     void update_infs (int *inds,
      int *inf_times,
      int *n,
      int *n_inf,
      int *locs,
      int *Rinds,
      double *logmean,
      double *logsd,
      double *alpha,
      double *wts,
      int *indices  /* a vector 1:n */
      ) { 
    ...

   /* set up GSL RNG */
   gsl_rng * rng = gsl_rng_alloc(gsl_rng_mt19937);
   /* end of GSL setup */
    ...
   gsl_ran_choose(rng, tmp_inf_me, Rinds[i], indices, *n, sizeof (double));
    ... }
```

Comment: why not simply sample without replacement without using R?

Comment: I am asking how to do that? I forgot to mention that I am trying to do it with weights.

Comment: Perhaps there is a way for me to call R's implementation of sample() from https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/random.c

Comment: Ah, yes weights make that slightly less trivial. If your question is "how do I sample without replacement with non-constant probabilities", that could be done without R - algorithms are available. And you can call R from C, but I'd be little use to you on that, not having done anything like that in a very long time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Likely the shared object needs to be compiled with a command like

```
export PKG_CFLAGS=`gsl-config --cflags`
export PKG_LIBS=`gsl-config --libs`
```

and then

```
R CMD SHLIB gsl.c
```

or alternatively

```
PKG_CFLAGS=`gsl-config --cflags` PKG_LIBS=`gsl-config --libs` R CMD SHLIB gsl.c
```

This is telling the compiler where to look for headers, and the linker where to find libraries to link against. During compilation and linking the commands should contain the output of `gsl-config --cflags` and `gsl-config --libs`, along the lines of

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/home/mtmorgan/bin/R-devel/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -fpi -c gsl.c -o gsl.o
```

during compilatoin and

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/local/lib64 -o gsl.so gsl.o -L/usr/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -L/home/mtmorgan/bin/R-devel/lib -lR
```

during linking. A test of success is

```
R -e 'dyn.load("gsl.so")'
```

In a package one would have a file `src/Makevars` with

```
PKG_CFLAGS = `gsl-config --cflags`
PKG_LIBS = `gsl-config --libs`
```

and, for Windows where `gsl-config` might not be available but the user has managed to install gsl and set an environment variable `LIB_GSL`, a file `src/Makevars.win`

```
PKG_LIBS += -L$(LIB_GSL)$(R_ARCH)/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm
PKG_CPPFLAGS += -I$(RHOME)/src/include -I$(LIB_GSL)$(R_ARCH)/include
```

Comment: Nice detailed answer -- but one can do all in *way less code* via the plugin of the RcppGSL package.

Answer (score 0):

I have had these kinds of "symbol not found" errors before when I forget an include or shared library -- both will be necessary in gsl, i.e., gcc -I/usr/include/gsl foo.c -o foo -l:/usr/lib/libgsl.so.

P.S., are the available sampling algorithms in R (sample(), or some of the external libs) just not performant enough?  I am surprised that this would be the bottleneck of all but a few really big data projects ...

Comment: sample() is totally great in R but seems annoying (an inefficient) to go back to R in the middle of C code.

Comment: ahh I figured you were just trying to wrap some C into R (Rcpp). :)

Comment: @scottyaz: Sorry to hear you can't / won't use Rcpp (can you share details?) -- a few days ago a sample() function in C++ (ie no GSL needed) was just posted to the rcpp-devel list.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I am pretty new to the C/C++ world after having used R for years.  The startup with using .C() and C seems to be easier but perhaps I haven't found the right resources.

Comment: I suspect you haven't. `.C()` may seem tempting, it is in fact very constraining as only `.Call()` can pass whole R objects back and forth.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Ok, I'll spend more time on some of the resources at your site. Have you seen (or produced) any presentations/documents for beginners?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel you were right! Rcpp was not that difficult. Thanks!